# Any way to fix a corrupt Custom Keyboard Settings file in Final Cut Pro v7?

Tags: final-cut-pro

I've been building up my custom keyboard layout for literally years; but it seems to be corrupt. Very often, when I try to add a key, Final Cut crashes (version 7.0.3)

Recreating it would take hours and hours.

If I start with a "fresh" keyboard map, FCP works fine. The "corrupt" file works until I try to add a new mapping. Then it crashes 80% of the time.

Is there any way to fix my keyboard file? Or isolate what is causing the issue?

Or does anyone know the syntax/format of the .fcmap file? Any way to open/edit it?

Comment: Try to isolate the cause. First save the custom keyboard settings to a file. Here it is explained how: http://www.larryjordan.biz/transferring-keyboard-layouts-to-another-final-cut-pro-system/ Back the file up and delete all custom keyboard settings. Try to add a key. See if FCP crashes. Import the saved keyboard settings file, add a key, see if it crashes.

Comment: I tried that years ago; didn't help.

Comment: OK, sad to hear that didn't work. So did FCP crash with the empty custom keyboard file? Or did it only crash with your custom keyboard file? Could you maybe add all the things you have tried to the question? This would help the people here to answer your question.

Comment: question updated.